# Are there any useful Silverlight Frameworks?

Tags: silverlight, frameworks

Are you using any framework (like [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) or [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362339.aspx))? What are your experiences with them and are they mature enough to use in production apps?

I would like to create a complete list of all frameworks:

- [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) (Guidance, MVVM)
- [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362339.aspx) (DI/IoC)
- [Enterprise Library 5.0 Silverlight Integration Pack](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight) (Validation, Logging, Exception Handling, Caching, Interception, flexible config)
- [Ninject](http://ninject.org/download) (DI/IoC)
- [.NET RIA Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76bb3a07-3846-4564-b0c3-27972bcaabce&displaylang=en) (Data)
- [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30098) (Extensibility)
- [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) (UI Patterns)
- [Caliburn](http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn) (UI Patterns)
- [Silverlight Extensions](http://www.slextensions.net/) (Controls/UI Patterns)
- [Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight) (Controls)
- [Silverlight Contrib](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/) (Controls)
- [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) (Unit Test)
- [nRoute Framework](http://nroute.codeplex.com/) (Application Flow)
- [Clog](http://clog.codeplex.com/) (Logging)
- [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/downloads.aspx) (Mocking)
- [Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/)
- [IronRuby and IronPython](http://sdlsdk.codeplex.com/) (Dynamic languages in SL)
- [DeepEarth](http://deepearth.codeplex.com/) (Mapping)
- [.NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) (Image manipulation)
- [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) (Graphics)

**Update:**

I've added a few to the list. I try to keep the list up-to-date with information from other sources.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Farseer Physics Engine](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) : An easy to use 2D physics engine designed for Microsoft’s Silverlight platform. The Farseer Physics Engine focuses on simplicity, useful features, and enabling the creation of fun, dynamic games.

[IronRuby and IronPython in Silverlight](http://sdlsdk.codeplex.com/) : The dynamic languages and Silverlight integration let you write browser applications with dynamic languages, like Ruby and Python. Please visit IronRuby or IronPython's websites' for using them in Silverlight.

[DeepEarth](http://deepearth.codeplex.com/):  An open source, standards oriented Silverlight mapping framework. It provides a rich framework for integrating and visualising spatial layers, services and data.

[Silverlight Contrib](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/) :  Silverlight Contrib is a collection of Silverlight Controls and API enhancements, and productivity tools built for and by the Silverlight developer community.

[.NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) :  ImageTools for Silverlight is a library, which provides additional functionality for loading, saving and manipulation images from different sources and with different formats.

[Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) : A 3D C# graphics engine for Microsoft Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

There are also:

- [Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight)
- [Ninject for Silverlight](http://ninject.org/download)

I've been using Ninject for a little while now and it's my favorite DI/IoC framework.

Also, note that SilverlightContrib has merged with SilverlightExtensions a while ago. I'm kind of afraid though to see no updates since then.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I found [Gestalt](http://www.visitmix.com/labs/gestalt/) which looks interesting. I'm not sure if it's a 'framework'.

Comment: I think Gestalt is more a web framework that can create loose xaml. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Also added the [Silverlight Integration Pack for Enterprise Library 5.0](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight) from [Microsoft patterns & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/practices), the same team that brought you Unity and Prism. Supports data caching (in-memory and isolated storage), logging (client and remote service), validation, exception handling and interception with flexibel configuration options (via external config, attributes or fluent interface).